# Anchor tikzpicture to other tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is this red box overlay not anchoring properly to the rectangle headerbox?

- Don't use xshift or yshift.
- I want that headerbox against the topmargin, now there is white space between them.
- Don't change "baseline=(headerbox.center)" in my headerbox description (so my tekst is centered. Use by example "\node at (headerbox.north east)..." to anchor the red box to it.

> Blockquote

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\newtab}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node[inner sep=2mm,text=white] (#1) {#2};
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[fill=red]%
        ($(#1.north east)$)%
        --($(#1.north west)$)%
        --($(#1.south west)$)%
        -- ($(#1.south east)$)%
        -- cycle;%
        \end{scope}%
        \end{tikzpicture}% 
}%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=0mm, outer sep=0pt,baseline=(headerbox.center)]%
\path node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth-\fboxrule,minimum height=3cm,draw=black,fill=white,inner xsep=0mm,inner ysep=0in](headerbox)%
{Headertekst}%
;%
\node at (headerbox.north east)[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, line width=0cm] {\newtab{headerbox}{Labeltekst}};
\end{tikzpicture}\par Test%
\end{document}
```

Blockquote[image]

Comment: You don't need to maintain that `baseline` to centre the text. You do need not to maintain it to get the vertical alignment you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

- "Cleaner" code
- \node[overlay], overlay is important at that node, otherwise the node takes space and the headerbox will move down.

Without that `(headerbox)` in node `at (headerbox.north east)(headerbox) {Tekst};` the red box doesn't show. Don't know why cause `(headerbox.north east)` specifies clearly where I want to put the red box. Anyway, this code works fine:

> Blockquote

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth-\fboxrule,minimum height=5cm,draw=black,fill=white,inner xsep=0mm,inner ysep=0in,rounded corners=0mm, outer sep=0pt,baseline=(headerbox.center)](headerbox){};%
\node[overlay,inner sep=2mm,text=white,anchor=south east] at (headerbox.north east)(headerbox){Tekst};%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]%
\draw[fill=red,overlay]%
($ (headerbox.north east) $)
--($ (headerbox.north west) $)
--($ (headerbox.south west) $)
--($ (headerbox.south east) $)
-- cycle;%
\end{scope};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Add an adjustment down for half the line width if that matters in your real document. I don't see you need all the libraries here, but still.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\newtab}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
      \node[inner sep=2mm,text=white] (#1) {#2};
      \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[fill=red]%
        ($(#1.north east)$)%
        --($(#1.north west)$)%
        --($(#1.south west)$)%
        -- ($(#1.south east)$)%
        -- cycle;%
      \end{scope}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=0mm, outer sep=0pt]%
    \path node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth-\fboxrule,minimum height=3cm,draw=black,fill=white,inner xsep=0mm,inner ysep=0in, anchor=north](headerbox) at (current page.north)
    {Headertekst}%
    ;%
    \node at (headerbox.north east)[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, line width=0cm] {\newtab{headerbox}{Labeltekst}};
  \end{tikzpicture}\par Test%
\end{document}
```

[image: tab]

The thickness of the line is partly an artefact and partly because half of the line width is above the line drawing the frame around the text area, I think.

Comment: Agreed. I ment the centered baseline is for vertically centering this box to another box (that is not shown in my code or picture).

Comment: I want the ability to pop-up that label or not. Adjustining vertically and horizontally makes the header wobbely when I pop the label.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to do. This isn't being created as a `header` at all. It is just the first thing on the page apart from the header ...

Comment: Here students have to put there names in. Just want to overlay the box, but it's odd...